# Update Mysqli using variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new in PHP. I want to update a MySQL table using variables.

```php
$sql = "UPDATE tableName 
           SET $variable1='$variable2' 
        WHERE table_no='$variable3'";
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you look it up in the documentation? It's pretty well explained.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I think your updated question's query will run; have you try this query? update your question with echo query

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mysqli_`. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

If you **HAVE** to use `mysqli_`, use a prepared statement:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
 $smth = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE tableName SET '.$variable1.'=? WHERE table_no=?');

 $smth->bind_param($variable2, $variable3);
```

That should do it, though I didn't run it. I encourage you to use PDO, though:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$query = $conn->prepare('UPDATE tableName SET '.$variable1.'=A WHERE table_no=B');
$query->bindParam('A', $variable2);
$query->bindParam('B', $variable3);
```

**EDIT**

Updated the `mysqli` section to use proper `bind_param` syntax.

Comment: That isn't my downvote that you got, but it seems you may have gotten it because of this `$smth->bindParam($variable2, $variable3);` which is PDO syntax and not `mysqli_`. And the missing quote `('UPDATE tableName SET '.$variable1.'=? WHERE table_no=?)`

Comment: The syntax for `mysqli_` is `bind_param()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php and not `bindParam()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you're totally right. Updated answer so I don't look like such an idiot anymore :)

Comment: That's great Zac. As you can see now, I've upvoted it, yet your answer now has a `0` which was "neutralized". OP however, is nowhere to be found.